# why can I not add an upstream git repo?

Tags: git, upstream-branch

I took a fork of master and master has received a few updates in the meantime that I now want to pull into my fork. So what I did was:
cloned the fork to local disk,
went into the dir and used `git remote add upstram http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp/path/to.git` to add the master as upstream repo. Then a `git fetch upstream` gives me:

```
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and I do have a clone of that master repo on my disk too so I sure have read access. What's the problem here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for replying this way, but I cannot comment.

Did you notice your command is:
git remote add **upstram** http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp/path/to.git

"upstram" not "upstream"?

I believe this could be the problem...

If you're not familiar with the command already - run "git remote -v" to see the remotes.

Answer (score 0):

In your command to add the remote you named **upstram**, not *upstream*. Check the name of your remotes: **git remote show**

Answer (score 0):

As I think you want to connect your local git repo with remote repo, here is my advice, considering using:`git remote set-url origin [your remote git repo url]` this is for changing your git remote repo link refs.

For a new local git repo you should use:`git remote add origin [your remote git repo url]`

I hope that would helps you.